# A compact Hausdorff space that is not Tychonoff

Tags: general-topology, examples-counterexamples

Is there an example of compact Haudorff that is not Tychonoff?

As every continuous function on compact space is bounded, then I was thinking maybe every compact Haudorff is Tychonoff but I failed to prove it.

Comment: Every compact Hausdorff space is *normal*, which is even stronger than Tychonoff.

Answer (score 2):

Every compact Hausdorff space is normal. Normal spaces are Tychonoff.

Comment: Just mentioning, some people use a different nomenclature where normality does not imply complete regularity. For those, the argument reads that every compact Hausdorff space is a $T_4$ space, hence a $T_{3\frac{1}{2}}$ space.